# linux memory map corruption?

Tags: linux, memory-management, shared-memory, mmap

I'm trying to locate the reason for what seems like a corruption in a memory map of a data struct.
Means of replication of this is by pulling the plug on the machine..

The code increments a member of the data struct by one sequentially and then calls `msync(..,MS_SYNC)` (which i understand is useful only in h/w failure cases, such as mine now).

My problem is that after restarting and remapping on the data, the particular counter is 'sometimes' incorrect, if so it is always less than what is should have been (by several hundred - this in terms of time would be a minute or so, not by a single count). I'm quite certain that `msync` would've completed hundreds of times before the 'crash' so i cant figure the reason for any gap bigger than 1 if any.

the rest of the data struct seems to have been flushed ok..

Has anyone come across something like this?

We're using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

Comment: How do you emulate "pulling the plug"? killing the process with sigkill?

Comment: @TurnaevEvgeny nope, i mean literally "pulling the plug" power off..

Comment: @TurnaevEvgeny sorry if i'm being vague, i mean physically pulling the power cable.